Conversion to svf fails
I am uploading step file to OSS and translating that to svf using the below code
async function TranslateToSVF(objectEncodedUrn) {
    console.log("Translating Object")
    const getAccessToken = await getAccessTokenFromLambda();
    let result = await axios.post('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job', {
        "input": {
            "urn": objectEncodedUrn
        },
        "output": {
            "destination": {
                "region": "us"
            },
            "formats": [
                {
                    "type": "svf",
                    "views": ["2d", "3d"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${getAccessToken} `
        }
    })
    do{
        
        result = await axios.get(`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${objectEncodedUrn}/manifest`,{
             headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${getAccessToken} `
            }
        })
        setTimeout(() => {}, 20000);
        console.log("inprogress!!!")
    }while(result.data.status === "inprogress" || result.data.status === "pending")
    console.log(result.data.status)

} 

The issue is same file tested already and its working fine but now its failing in the translation.And getting response as :
{'type': 'manifest', 'hasThumbnail': 'true', 'status': 'failed', 'progress': 'complete', 'region': 'US', 'urn': 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW50ZWNoX2xhdHRpY2VfZGVtby9ncmlwcGVyX2FybV83Y2I1M2Y2Ny1hMDMxLTRhNDItOGQwNS05NjJhY2EzNWFjNDIuc3RlcA', 'version': '1.0', 'derivatives': [{'name': 'gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.step', 'hasThumbnail': 'true', 'status': 'failed', 'progress': 'complete', 'messages': [{'type': 'error', 'code': 'ATF-1036', 'message': ['Schema of the file format is not supported.', 'C:\\worker\\viewing-atf-lmv-cosv3\\tmp\\job-1\\104\\gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.step']}], 'outputType': 'svf', 'children': [{'guid': '5cc6d9c7-e4d4-465b-a46e-46800cf0837c', 'type': 'geometry', 'role': '3d', 'name': 'Scene', 'status': 'success', 'progress': 'complete', 'hasThumbnail': 'true', 'children': [{'guid': '39afe01b-4aff-4b26-b431-58f81e902831', 'type': 'resource', 'urn': 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW50ZWNoX2xhdHRpY2VfZGVtby9ncmlwcGVyX2FybV83Y2I1M2Y2Ny1hMDMxLTRhNDItOGQwNS05NjJhY2EzNWFjNDIuc3RlcA/output/1/gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.svf', 'role': 'graphics', 'mime': 'application/autodesk-svf'}, {'guid': '938aed2b-9c22-47ab-bcf4-b5a57029c625', 'type': 'resource', 'urn': 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW50ZWNoX2xhdHRpY2VfZGVtby9ncmlwcGVyX2FybV83Y2I1M2Y2Ny1hMDMxLTRhNDItOGQwNS05NjJhY2EzNWFjNDIuc3RlcA/output/1/gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.svf.png01_thumb_400x400.png', 'resolution': [400, 400], 'mime': 'image/png', 'role': 'thumbnail'}, {'guid': 'dfe96868-5b4e-4b91-8b73-38fa8555c66a', 'type': 'resource', 'urn': 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW50ZWNoX2xhdHRpY2VfZGVtby9ncmlwcGVyX2FybV83Y2I1M2Y2Ny1hMDMxLTRhNDItOGQwNS05NjJhY2EzNWFjNDIuc3RlcA/output/1/gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.svf.png01_thumb_200x200.png', 'resolution': [200, 200], 'mime': 'image/png', 'role': 'thumbnail'}, {'guid': '225bcaa8-6d4b-48b1-930c-50910d745570', 'type': 'resource', 'urn': 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW50ZWNoX2xhdHRpY2VfZGVtby9ncmlwcGVyX2FybV83Y2I1M2Y2Ny1hMDMxLTRhNDItOGQwNS05NjJhY2EzNWFjNDIuc3RlcA/output/1/gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.svf.png01_thumb_100x100.png', 'resolution': [100, 100], 'mime': 'image/png', 'role': 'thumbnail'}]}, {'guid': 'd48b29e0-6245-483d-9ff6-be2caf5de578', 'type': 'resource', 'urn': 'urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW50ZWNoX2xhdHRpY2VfZGVtby9ncmlwcGVyX2FybV83Y2I1M2Y2Ny1hMDMxLTRhNDItOGQwNS05NjJhY2EzNWFjNDIuc3RlcA/output/1/properties.db', 'role': 'Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase', 'mime': 'application/autodesk-db', 'status': 'success'}]}]}

It should give status as success.What should be issue?

If you place your response object in https://jsoneditoronline.org/ and check res.derivatives[0].childen[0], progress is complete and the status is a success. only for thumbnail it has failed, some files may not have thumbnail, but the SVF translation which can be viewed in the APS viewer is a success in your case.
You can check at https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/ and view the model in the viewer.

How we can decide that failed response is because of thumbnail. There is one error code that showing
"messages": [
{
"type": "error",
"code": "ATF-1036",
"message": [
"Schema of the file format is not supported.",
"C:\worker\viewing-atf-lmv-cosv3\tmp\job-1\104\gripper_arm_7cb53f67-a031-4a42-8d05-962aca35ac42.step"
]
}
]

it's clearly shown: 'type': 'manifest', 'hasThumbnail': 'true', 'status': 'failed'
